# Can I override using subclass object as parameter in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I have classes as follows

```
public class Useful 
{
    public void f(Object a)
    {
        System.out.println("In base f");
    }

    public void g(String a)
    {
        System.out.println("In base g");
    }
}

public class MoreUseful extends Useful 
{
    public void f(String a)
    {
        System.out.println("In derived f");
    }

    public void g(Object a)
    {
        System.out.println("In derived g");
    }
}
```

I am trying to override base class method but I am changing the parameters in derived class.
in method MoreUseful.f() I am using subclass parameter (String) as against Object in base class.
in method MoreUseful.g() I am using superclass parameter (Object) as against String in base class.

Is it possible to override these way?
Which of the above two cases will be correct overriding?

Comment: Whenever it comes to overriding always use the annotation `@Override` then the compiler itself will tell you if you cannot do that or if something is wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/q/94361/738746

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible, and would be a violation of the [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

By inheriting from a class, you express that your subclass `MoreUseful` is actually a `Useful` and therefore exposes *all the functionality* that `Useful` exposes. If you removed the ability to invoke `f` with an object, you'd break that promise.

You are free to *overload* `f` so that you have an `f(String s)` method though.

Answer (score 0):

The `g()` method is indeed overriden. `f()`, however, is not overriden - it's **overloaded**. An easy way to verify this is to add `@Override` on each method you intend to override - if it results in a compilation error, you aren't overriding properly.